# Graphs on Atlas not updating

Tags: relays, atlas, nyx

I recently started running a relay on my NAS. While the relay itself is running fine (no errors from tor itself), and I understand that I won't get much traffic for the first two days (I've read [this](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) article), I have some problems with the graphs on atlas:

The graphs on the [details page of my relay](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/AF0FB2C1E7F964A19DE346794FA0B0E37B6FE33F) are not updating. They still show only data up until 2015-03-04 9AM (for the bandwidth graph) or 7:30PM for the consensus weight graph. 
They also didn't change at all since I checked them yesterday evening.

Is there something wrong with my relay? And if so, how do I fix it?

P.S.: when I check on my relay with arm, I get this message (among others):

```
[ARM_NOTICE] Read the last day of bandwidth history from the state file (7 hours is missing)
```

Comment: Same is happening to me, it is a server side problem with torproject.org.

Comment: It works now. Was probably related with the onionoo server outage that happened shortly after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor recently switched to providing bandwidth history in 4-hour intervals rather than 15-minute intervals. This caused a lot of the bandwidth displaying tools to have issues with displaying the histories. These issues should be raised on [Tor's bug tracker](https://trac.torproject.org) for the individual components if they haven't been mentioned there already so they can be fixed individually. Depending on how well maintained each project is, the fix shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 1):

Same with Globe. I'm getting the same things as you since last night at around 8 PM CST. Appears to be a problem with the main Tor website. Just give it a few hours. I'm sure they are working on it already. :)